# Is the strawberry lemonade sugar free slurpee drink kosher in Quick Check?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I want to know if the quick check slurpees are kosher since it's not seven eleven and I can only find the kashrus for seven eleven online.

Comment: Have you contacted the company?

Comment: Saw this if relevant - https://lakewoodalerts.com/kashrus-concerns-mounting-at-popular-lakewood-quickchek/

Comment: The quick check in Lakewood has a renewed kashrus certificate hanging there

Comment: Ask your local rabbi. It can vary from place to place, which is why it's not listed online.

Comment: There is no supervision, so you have to ask your rabbi if the kashrus of the original syrup is enough for you. If it is, you can always ask to see the packaging while at the store, and if you're polite and they are not busy most places are OK with showing it to you.